# Flutter - How does Column constrain its height inside a ListView when its default mainAxisSize = max?

Tags: flutter

What magic allows ListView to constrain its children to their minimal intrinsic size during layout?

---

According to `Column` [layout algorithm](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Column-class.html), it tries to be as tall as possible (by default).

Inside a `ListView`, during `performLayout` the height constraint for a `Sliver` child is `double.INFINITY` (if I'm not mistaken).

How does `Column` constrain its height to its intrinsic height (i.e. the minimum required to contain its children) when its incoming height constraint inside a `ListView` is infinity?

Here's sample code I played with trying to understand this.

Uncommenting `child: MyColumn()` while commenting out `child:ListView()` shows `Column` expanding to its usual max height.  But inside a `ListView` it's magically constrained to its minimal height.  I'm wondering how this is done.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class FlexInListViewPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Column in ListView'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(width: 3, color: Colors.lightGreenAccent)
        ),
        //child: MyColumn() // ← uncomment while commenting out ↓ to see Column & its default height
        child: ListView(// imposes tight constraint of screen width to children
          children: [ /// RenderSliverList performLayout doesn't impose a constraint height during layout
            /// but asks children to report back size after layout complete
            /// this allows ListView to pass a height constraint to Column
            Container(child: Text('child'), color: Colors.yellowAccent,),
            Container(child: MyColumn(), color: Colors.orangeAccent.withOpacity(.5),)
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyColumn extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    /// Column
    /// 1: layout fixed-height (zero flex factor) children in unbounded vertical space
    /// 2: Calculate/reserve remaining space for flex-height children
    /// 3: No flex children, skip flex-kids layout
    /// 4: Width is either widest child, or width imposed by parent (ListView: screen width)
    /// 5: Height of Column is by default mainAxisSize: max, try to fill all vert. space
    /// 5: If mainAxisSize: min & incoming vert. constraints allow,
    /// height of Column is sum of children heights
    return Column(
      children: [
        Container(child: Text('inside Column'), color: Colors.lightBlueAccent.withOpacity(.3),)
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

What the above code renders:

[image: Column inside ListView, magically constrained]

#### Notes

I've seen the code for `parentUsesSize` where layout size is reported back up from children to parent, but I don't understand how `Column` is sizing itself to minimal height when its constraint is unbounded.  Is there some non-obvious information being passed around, something like "minimal needed layout size" vs. "desired layout size"?

Comment: I believe this is related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75290803/why-doesnt-a-column-inside-of-a-column-throw-an-infinite-height-error. Have you figured out the answer since you originally posted?

Answer (score -1):

im assuming this is what you want to achieve,
Inside your ListView add `shrinkWrap: true` and `primary: false`

```
ListView(// imposes tight constraint of screen width to children
            primary: false,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            children: [ /// RenderSliverList performLayout doesn't impose a constraint height 
            during layout
            /// but asks children to report back size after layout complete
            /// this allows ListView to pass a height constraint to Column
            Container(child: Text('child'), color: Colors.yellowAccent,),
            Container(child: MyColumn(), color: Colors.orangeAccent.withOpacity(.5),)
          ],
```

Comment: Appreciate the reply, but I'm not trying to reduce the size of the ListView. I'm looking for an explanation of how `Column` is *not* expanding to take up the entire `ListView`, which by default, according to its layout algorithm, as I understand, it should.