# Why doesn't a Column inside of a Column throw an infinite height error?

Tags: flutter

In Flutter, if you put a ListView inside of a Column:

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Column(
    children: [
      ListView(),
    ],
  );
}
```

You get a "Vertical viewport was given unbounded height" error. This makes sense, because Column introduces an infinite height constraint and ListView tries to grow to the maximum possible height. If you put a ListView inside a ListView, you get the same error.

However, if you put a Column inside a ListView or a Column inside a Column:

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Column(
    children: [
      Column(),
    ],
  );
}
```

You don't get any errors. Why not?

The default `mainAxisSize` for a Column is `MainAxisSize.max` and (again) Columns and ListViews introduce an infinite height constraint, so it seems to me that the inner Column would be infinitely tall, therefore causing a layout error.

There must be some fundamental difference between Column and ListView that I'm missing. I understand that the latter is a scrolling widget and the former is not, but that doesn't connect the dots for me.

Comment: Thanks for the poke on my question.  I re-read Column's layout procedure and still don't understand how Col in Col doesn't expand to max vertical constraint.  The only clue I see is a private method `_getIntrinsicSize` inside `RenderFlex` class.  I assume there's some logic to calculate the smallest intrinsic size *when inside another renderflex widget*, but otherwise expand to max. Maybe?

Comment: @Baker I think you may be on to something. I was reading the same code yesterday and noticed the `canFlex` variable. It seems that if the incoming height constraint is infinite, a large portion of flex-specific code is skipped (although there's still a check that throws an error if any Flexible children are found). What you're saying corresponds to what I'm seeing when I set different-color backgrounds for the app window, the outer Column, and the inner Column—outer Col stretches to maximum height, inner Col shrinks to min content.